# how can i generate linkedin company page access token?

Tags: linkedin-api

We are developing social automation tools to create posts on LinkedIn company pages. We have successfully generated access tokens for individual users and utilized them to create posts. However, we are currently facing a challenge in generating access tokens specifically for company pages. Could you provide guidance on how to generate access tokens for company pages, as we have not found any corresponding API for this purpose?
Thank you.